# Is there a way to pause animateWithDuration once it has started?

Tags: iphone, ios, animation

I'm using animateWithDuration method to animate a textView with lyrics to a song that scrolls as the song plays. It works fine, but I included a pause button for the song and obviously when paused the animation continues scrolling. Is there a way to pause this. I looked at the class reference from Apple and saw there were a few delay methods, but those are meant for use before the animation begins. So was just curious if there was a way to pause/restart the animation when the user pauses/unpauses the song. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may start a new animation that moves your textView to the current/displayed position with Duration: 0.0f (when pressing the Pause button), it will cancel/skip the previous animation  ;-)

Comment: I thought about htis, but it would only work if there was a way to determine the CGPoint of the textView being animated, so I could stop the animation at that point once paused and resume starting at that point once play is pressed again. So far I haven't been able to find one. Is there a way to find the top most CGPoint of the textView being animated?

Comment: I've tried the following code to no avail...

    CGPoint scrollPoint = textView.bounds.origin;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0 animations:^(void) {[textView setContentOffset:scrollPoint];}];`

Also tried 
`
    CGPoint scrollPoint = textView.contentOffset;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0 animations:^(void) {[textView setContentOffset:scrollPoint];}];`

Also tried [self.view.layer removeAllAnimations]; But I suspect since I'm calling the animation on UIView, calling for removal on the layer wouldn't do much of anything...

Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @CABearsfan If I were you, I'll use a NSTimer instead of UIAnimatin. Update the position in the NSTimer run loop: scrollPoint=CGPointMake(lastPoint.x,lastPoint.y+1); lastPoint=scrollPoint; So you can stop it when ever you want;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could count how much time passed since the start of animation and calculate the offset at the moment of pausing.
There should be a more simpler solution though.
Maybe NSString drawAtPoint in drawRect, using a timer to repeatedly call drawRect to update the position.